# How much RAM can I put in an ASUS Q550LF?

Tags: laptop, memory, asus-laptop, memory-limit

I'm thinking about upgrading my laptop's RAM and I've been wondering two things:

1. How many RAM slots does my laptop have? I've been looking online and I can't seem to find a clear answer.
2. How much ram can my computer actually run with? I know some MOBO's and OS versions are limited to a certain amount of RAM, and I don't want to buy more than my PC can handle.

I have an ASUS Q550LF with Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit) installed.

Comment: The manual doesn't say ( http://www.asus.com/supportonly/Q550LF/HelpDesk_Manual/ ), according to ( http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834231446 ) it sounds like it has 2 slots supporting 8GB dimms ASSUMING THAT'S THE EXACT SAME MODEL YOU HAVE, and according to ( http://ark.intel.com/products/75460/Intel-Core-i7-4500U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_00-GHz ) the i7-4500u is capable of handling 16GB of ram. You should update your answer to specify the full product id, as Q550LF is just the first part, they may be sub-versions, and revisions that carry slightly different hardware.

Comment: It's worth noting that many laptops that come with 8gb of ram use 2x4gb dimms which means ditching an old dimm to free up a slot for the new ram dimm. To see if your computer has done so you'll have to open it up, and look (which may void your warranty if still in effect as may doing the actual upgrade).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to <strike>[Crucial](http://images.crucial.com/upgrade/ASUS-memory/ASUS+Notebooks/Q550LF-upgrades.html)</strike> [new address](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for//q550lf#memoryResults), the maximum memory supported by ASUS Q550LF Laptop/Notebook is 16GB—a kit with 2 slots, that is 8GBx2. The supported memory types are DDR3 PC3-12800, DDR3 PC3-14900, DDR3 (non-ECC).

Comment: I would be cautious about getting DDR3 PC3-14900 (aka 1866mhz) as on the Intel website it says i7-4500u supports 1333mhz, and 1600mhz; it does not list 1866mhz.

Comment: @abc123, your link is broken.